# File system compatible with all OSes?

Tags: linux, filesystems, osx, windows

I use Linux and Mac OS X on a regular basis, and sometimes I have to use Windows. I need to use a flash drive on all three, and I need a filesystem that will work well on all of them. None of the ext's work on Mac or Windows, HFS+ doesn't work on Windows (or well on Linux), NTFS is read-only on Mac, and FAT sucks on all OSes. Is there a file system that would work reasonably well on all operating systems? I'd like it to work without drivers or additional installations, so it can be used on any computer.

Comment: Here is the answer: [Cross-platform file system](http://superuser.com/q/45130/105023)

Comment: @Marco `I'd like it to work without drivers or additional installations, so it can be used on any computer.`

Comment: If you want files larger than 4GiB there's just one choice, UDF.

Comment: @Marco I don't see that in GParted, how can I make a UDF partition?

Comment: With `mkudffs` from the package `udftools`.

Comment: @Marco you might want to add that as an answer

Comment: Please note that Linux, OS X and Windows are not all OSes.

Comment: @moose should I replace every instance of "Linux" with "Linux kernel with GNU coreutils and the Cinnamon desktop environment"?

Comment: @tkbx there are OSes like RISC OS or MACH which are not related to Windows or Linux. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_operating_systems for many more. The Unix family tree might also be interesting for you: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Unix_history-simple.svg

Comment: By the way, I don't understand your answer to my note. What do you mean?

Comment: @moose oh, I thought you meant that not all of Linux, Mac, and Windows fall into the category of "OSes" (linux technically being a kernel, not an operating system). I was under the impression that anything but weird experiments like Haiku were compatible with Linux software, hardware, etc.

Comment: [Universal File System](https://askubuntu.com/q/898716/253474), [Cross-Platform File System file sharing between MAC, WINDOWS, LINUX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/170407)

Comment: Consider also using a remote/distributed revision-control-system. This will allow you to side-step the problem, and will solve many other problems.

Comment: See also: [Super User: Cross-platform file system](https://superuser.com/q/45130/425838)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[UDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format) is a candidate. It works out-of-the-box on linux >= 2.6.31, Windows >= Vista, MacOS >= 9 and on many BSDs.

*Note:* UDF comes in different versions, which are not equally supported on all platforms, see [Wikipedia - Compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format#Compatibility).

UDF can be created on Linux with the tool `mkudffs` from the package `udftools`.

Comment: Wait, Vista and later will recognize UDF on flash or regular hard disks?  Last time I tried that I guess it was XP thought it was only for optical media.  That's good news.

Comment: I don't have a windows to test, but I would assume that it works for both. If the OS contains a driver to read UDF what would be a reason to not use it for a particular storage backend technology? And what would happen if the regular disk is a flash drive? Well, I guess in that case it works just *sometimes*.

Comment: I assumed the same thing but last time I tried it, Microsoft stupidly refused to recognize it on a hard disk/flash drive, even though they could on a cdrom.

Comment: @Marco looks like 2.0 is the version I'll use. Is it that newer version of UDF drop support of OSes, or newer OS versions drop support of UDF?

Comment: @Marco I'm afraid that for Windows the implication "have a fs driver" => "will work on any media" is not guaranteed. Why that is is another question, but I just wouldn't take it for granted. It would expect it to work for DVD-RAM for though.

Comment: Careful about the format tool and options, check this thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/55089/with-what-tool-should-i-format-a-hard-drive-as-udf

Comment: Since September 2006 due to CVE-2006-4145 kernel has disabled writing extents larger than 1Gb in size. In order to write files larger than 1Gb UDF driver should be updated to write more extents for a file. This has not happened till present (2015), so on linux UDF has been even worse than FAT32 for years.

Comment: Wish I could downvote.  This does not work.

Answer (score 17):

Without troubles, use FAT32. There is no other compatible possibility. Linux since version 2.6.xy has no more problems with NTFS, but Mac OS does...Maybe you could make more partitions at your flash, but this is actualy not great solution.

Other solution:
Try to imagine you have 4GB flash memory.
Split it to 2 partitions.
1) FAT32 with freeware portable applications to access all other FS types. 
2) Universal partition, which can be whatever you want - NTFS, ReiserFS (if you want real security and encryption) or whatever. Thanks first partition of your flash memory, you can easily read/write from whatever OS, because of programms you have stored at your FAT32 partition of your flash memory.

Better solution:
Forget using a flash drive. Use Dropbox or something through network. They are one of the simplest ways of sharing files between machines.

edit: Thank you for correction: let me write one of comments here:
" the maximum size depends on the selected cluster size. The limits really are from 2TB to 16TB for cluster sizes 512B to 4KB for FAT32 (also mentioned on the wikipage)."
That is right, excuse my mistake.

Thank you peterph

Comment: I agree.  If you have to use a USB stick, FAT32 is really your only choice. Note that limits you to 4 Gb per partition.

Comment: No, that is not truth. FAT32 limits only maximum filesize to 4GB, but I have seen FAT32 partitions sizes more than 200GB. So maximum size of FAT32 is 512GB per partition. look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table

Comment: @MIrra but a 640GB HDD of mine came as FAT32...

Comment: @MIrra the maximum size depends on the selected cluster size. The limits really are from 2TB to 16TB for cluster sizes 512B to 4KB for FAT32 (also mentioned on the wikipage).

Comment: Anyone at this skill level should never ever have to touch any untrusted 3rd party storage like Dropbox. Just use sshfs on your server, which should work out of the box, and be done with it. Yes, there are [many SSHFS clients for Windows](http://alternativeto.net/software/webdrive/?platform=windows), offering normal mounting abilities.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Dropbox is no more secure solution, as we know better solution might be for example owncloud installed on your own server, or to use sshfs client as Evi1m4chine said.

Answer (score 12):

Since you have cut it to the filesystems supported by OS X and Windows out of the box, I'm afraid the least common denominator is FAT32. [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) might be an option if you can relax the requirement and accept using FUSE - it is patent encumbered and hence it isn't going to  make it to kernel till 2029 or until Microsoft grants the patent on royalty-free basis, whichever happens first.

Update: Microsoft publicly released the [exFAT specification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/exfat-specification) in 2019 and exFAT is available as kernel driver in [Linux 5.4+](https://lwn.net/Articles/805462/). For additional information see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT#Adoption), [MS blog](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2019/08/28/exfat-linux-kernel/).

On the other hand, remember that lots of informed people would argue that exFAT trades of functionality for simplicity. Thus you will get something that is capable of storing data and works across various OSes, but feature-wise is rather rudimentary.

Comment: Now, I just have to wonder why Apple and Microsoft can't get off their proprietary horse and support ext.

Comment: @tkbx It would mean more work for them (to get such code **from scratch** up to their standards), and not many users are complaining, I guess (and by "many" I mean "big corporate users that could cause bad publicity"). Those that do complain usually decide to use some open-source solution as an add-on (i.e. thay don't have the requirement for it to work without any additional software).

Comment: Also, let's hope there isn't a Windows in 2029.

Comment: @tkbx If I remember correctly people stopped using it in 2033, and they were then just a cloud platform provider. However the use of 3 character file-name extensions carried on for years at least to 2099.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest [`exFAT`](https://github.com/relan/exfat). Here's why:

- It works in RW everywhere (unlike NTFS, that's supported read only on Mac OSX), it's included in Windows since Windows XP and in Mac OSX since Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), and afaik all the GNU/Linux distros out there includes packages for it in default repos.
  Even Android devices, iOS devices (iPhones and iPads), and some smart TVs support it as of year 2017.
- It doesn't support permissions and ownership of files (unlike ext2/3/4, NTFS and HFS+), and it's a good thing, since they can be very annoying on a flash drive that you often connect to several, different, computers.
- It supports large disks and big file systems without wasting space, and supports files bigger than 4GB (unlike FAT32).
  It supports almost any unicode character in file and directory names (unlike FAT32
- It's simple enough to be fast (unlike NTFS) and reliable (unlike FAT32).
- With SDXC cards exFAT became the standard for SD and micro SD cards with storage bigger than 32 GB, so one can expect support for it in most recent cameras, camcorders, smartphones and game consoles. So even if you don't think to need it, maybe you already have one or more devices using it or ready for it.

Unfortunately, **patents on exFAT** prevent to include it in mainline Linux kernel, so you need to manually install an implementation of exFAT to add support for it in your system. Anyways, once you install it, the system will be able to mount or unmount it using normal mechanisms.

Most distros provide packages to install a FUSE implementation that works fine and flawlessly. I used it for flash drives, SD cards and external USB disks, and I'm happy with it.

I'd expect a FUSE file system to be slower than a native one, but most often the bottle neck is in the hardware, not in the file system (often flash drives themselves are slower than file system drivers), so for "normal" use it won't be a problem at all.

To use exFAT on Ubuntu and Debian you just need to install the `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` packages:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: The exfat driver for macos is not as full-featured as on windows, and on mac the drive often gets the dirty flag set, as result you might need to to wait for hours (on multi-TB drives) the next time you plug it it because `fsck_exfat` has to finish checking it. The linux driver for exfat is userland and often leads to high CPU. There is a kernel-mode exfat linux driver but that's not official and can be buggy.

Comment: It's true, exfat is proprietary (but recently Microsoft seems to be willing to solve this), and current Linux and MacOS implementations have limitations, but imho it's still the best modern file system for interoperability.

Comment: Agreed, given the lack of a better alternative exfat _is_ currently the lowest common denominator and works even with android devices (with a OTG cable you can connect flash and hdd drives formatted as exfat). It lacks symlinks and permissions support, is not compatible with NFS but otherwise is ok for data storage. On Mac it can be problematic when the dirty bit gets set; I've described a workaround here: https://superuser.com/a/1491743/65975

Comment: The fact that exFAT is also accessible to Android and even iOS is a great plus.

Comment: Patents problems seems to be solved, and since Linux 5.7 (2020-04) good exfat file system support is included in the kernel, so now there isn't any reason  to not use it. See https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=New-exFAT-For-Linux-5.7

Answer (score 0):

### Which filesystem to use for Windows, Mac, and Linux?

##### Quick summary:

**exFAT** on an SSD, with 8 KiB cluster size. exFAT is natively read/writable on all 3 OSs, without any additional installation, configuration, or work. And the 8 KiB cluster size is a good tradeoff between speed and wasted space (study the plots I produced at the bottom of this answer).

You can also consider NTFS, but it requires extra drivers for MacOS to write on it. See the bottom of my answer for links.

More detail:

1. Linux only: ext4
2. Windows only: ntfs
3. MacOs only: apfs
4. Linux & Windows: ntfs
5. Mac & Windows: exFAT
6. Linux & Mac: exFAT
7. Windows, Mac, & Linux: exFAT

##### Long answer:

Here's what I recommend you format your filesystem to for Linux, Windows, and Mac.

1. For single OS use:

   1. For **Linux use only**, including on external hard drives, format your filesystem as **ext4** via the gparted GUI. EXT4 is a Linux file format. This is what I use the most, even on external hard drives, since I'm a heavy Linux user.

      1. For optional encryption, use LUKS, which can be configured through the Gnome Disks GUI.
   2. For **Windows use only**, format the filesystem as **ntfs** via the gparted GUI.

      1. For optional encryption, use a [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html) container stored on the NTFS partition. If running the NTFS filesystem *in* Windows, you can encrypt your whole disk using VeraCrypt, but that works for Windows only with this tool.
   3. For **MacOS use only**, format the filesystem as **apfs** (Apple Filesystem). This must be done on a Mac via the Mac Disks utility. There are several format options available in this utility, as shown here, including "APFS", "APFS (Encrypted)", "APFS (Case-sensitive)", "APFS (Case-sensitive, Encrypted)":
      [image]

      1. There is currently no fully-functional APFS open source implementation available on any operating system today, that I am aware of, as Apple wants. They like to have their equipment be as incompatible as possible. You can see some tools here though: [Super User: How to mount APFS on Linux or Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/1267291/425838)
      2. For optional encryption, turn on the File Vault encryption inside the MacOS security settings.
2. For shared OS use:

   1. For sharing files between **Linux and Windows**, use **ntfs**, formatted via the gparted GUI. NTFS is a Microsoft file format, but Linux, such as Linux Ubuntu, fully supports both reading and writing to it with no additional configuration.

      1. For optional encryption, use a [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html) container stored on the NTFS partition.
   2. For sharing files between **Mac and Windows**, **Linux and Mac**, **Windows and Mac**, or **Windows, Mac, and Linux**, use **exFAT**, formatted via the command-line on Linux, as I show in my article on my website here: [exFAT filesystem speed and disk usage based on cluster size - Formatting an exFAT drive on Linux Ubuntu](https://gabrielstaples.com/exfat-clusters/#formatting-an-exfat-drive-on-linux-ubuntu).

      1. ExFAT is a Microsoft file format, but its specifications have apparently been fully released, and Windows, Mac, and Linux all support reading and writing to it without additional configuration on any system. Both Mac and Windows have exFAT as a format option in their disk GUI utilities as well, and Linux supports formatting to this type as well via the Gnome Disks utility and the command line, which I show below. You can also use FAT32, but it is much more limited than exFAT, particular with its 4 GiB maximum file size limit, as shown in the "Limits" table [from Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/filesystem-functionality-comparison), so I strongly recommend exFAT instead.
      2. For optional encryption, use a [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html) container stored on the exFAT partition.

Note: when formatting your exFAT partition, I recommend a cluster size of 8 KiB. 128 KiB gets you slightly better speed, but wastes a lot more disk space if you have a lot of small files. Don't go higher than that or else you waste a ton of disk space when you have small files.

See my plots here for details:

[image]

Read more here:

1. My answer: [Is it best to reformat the hard drive to exFAT using 512kb chunk, or smaller or bigger chunks?](https://superuser.com/a/1785239/425838)
2. My website article: https://gabrielstaples.com/exfat-clusters/
3. My full Python matplotlib/numpy plotting code is here: https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/stack_exchange/format_exFAT_PLOTS.py

##### NTFS drivers for MacOS:

**exFAT**'s big downside is it doesn't support symlinks. In that case, maybe consider **NTFS**. It's compatible natively with Windows and Linux, and with some extra drivers you can make it work for writing on MacOS. Ex: https://toolbox.easeus.com/ntfs-for-mac/index.html Or a free tool is mentioned here: https://superuser.com/a/45144/425838