# Type of filesystem to put on USB storage, that is compatible with most OSs

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb

I want to format a USB storage device from the terminal and I have found several formats to do it. It's the first time I'm going to do this and I have doubts. I want to do it well. I have these options and I want to know which one is convenient that is compatible with all operating systems.

```
# mkfs.vfat -n 'dickEt' -I /dev/sdd1
# mkfs.ntfs -n 'dickEt' -I /dev/sdd1
# mkfs.ext2 -n 'dickEt' -I /dev/sdd1
# mkfs.ext3 -n 'dickEt' -I /dev/sdd1
# mkfs.ext4 -n 'dickEt' -I /dev/sdd1
# mkfs.msdos -n 'dickEt' -I /dev/sdd1
# mkfs.xfs -n 'dickEt' -I /dev/sdd1
# mkfs.bfs -n 'dickEt' -I /dev/sdd1
```

Comment: vfat is compatible with most OS (even Microsoft's Windows). I can't remember the difference between it and msdos.

Comment: I did not know that this format is compatible with all. Thank you @ctrl-alt-delor

Comment: A secondary consideration is the maximum file-size you want to store ... different fs' have different limitations.

Comment: I believe you duplicated vfat

Comment: I usually save temporary programming data. I found this pendrive in my room and I want to use it. On my laptop, I use Manjaro, on my other laptop I have Raspbian and my brother uses Windows.

Comment: The following link may help you select file system, [Different scenarios and files systems are examined looking for alternatives taking into account: 1. the file size problem; 2.which operating systems that should read/write the USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706)

Comment: Compatible with *all* operating systems? That might be hard.

Comment: I wonder if an ISO 9660 (CD-ROM) filesystem would work...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. It's the first time I do this

Comment: @JeffSchaller. The iso 9660 file system is read-only on a mass storage device (for example USB pendrive). So it is only an alternative for a CD/DVD disk.

Comment: If read-only is enough for the OP...?

Comment: Reading and writing

Comment: duplicate: [File system compatible with all OSes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59585/44425), [file system to use with OS X, Linux and Windows in 2016](https://superuser.com/q/1161120/241386), [Cross-platform file system](https://superuser.com/q/45130/241386), [What filesystem to use when using both Windows and Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/225560/241386), [Best filesystem for use with multiple OS?](https://superuser.com/q/78682/241386), [Best file system for external (USB) hard drives/USB memory media](https://serverfault.com/q/3868/343888)

Comment: **Voted to reopen** to be able to close as duplicate of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59585/44425)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to your question¹ is simple:

```
mkfs.msdos -n 'dickEt' -I /dev/sdd1
```

*Hoever,* it comes with the following limitations:

- Maximum file size is 4GB
- Maximum partition size is 2TB

**OS - File system compatibility (mini) matrix:**

```
                   FAT  NTFS EXT[2..4] BTRFS  XFS HPFS
Amiga               x
MS-DOS, Win95, 98   x
NT, W2K, ... W10    x     x      2
MacOS               x     3      4                  x
Linux               x     x      x       x      x   x
```

<sub>**Note 1:** You asked for maximum OS compatibility and that's the only answer as it is compatible with *most OSes* as it's one of the oldest and least capable file systems. (**Not ALL OSes!** E.G. C64 does not support FAT!)

**Note 2:** Commercial Tryware if you want write capabilities.

**Note 3:** Commercial Software if you want write capabilities.

**Note 4:** [Read-only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/210198/297223)</sub>

Comment: May be useful for some who try to mount ext4 on Mac OS X: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/210198/297223  Also here's one for using  NTFS there: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/447/297223

Comment: Here, clarify that the question refers to what type of format is recommended for a Pen Drive, ntfs, fat, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use NTFS.

FAT can be also OK, but for large files (> 4GB) you need at least exFAT. Also FAT can end in having all your files on it marked as executable, when viewed from *nix systems.

NTFS should be readable and writable by all major operating systems. 
Only at some models of printers and scanners, which generally would support USB sticks as source/target, you can have bad luck with NTFS – these usually than need a msdos partition table (not GPT partition table) with the first primary partition formatted as FAT32.

So if you do not need printer/scanner support, use the whole stick as NTFS, else make a first small primary partition FAT32, and NTFS for the rest. To be on the safe side, use only msdos type partition table, not GPT, as GPT might only be supported by newer systems.

Comment: I would never recommend NTFS as a "compatible" filesystem. It is not writable by macOS, nor is it even readable by default on most Linux installations. FAT32 is preferred by far. File too big? Just use `split`

Comment: Mac isn't in the *practical* list of "all systems" buried in the comments. And I've not had a problem reading (or writing) NTFS on a Linux-based system for years now.

Comment: "NTFS *should* be readable and writable", but in practise is often not. The only OS fully supporting NTFS out of the box is Windows, the rest sometimes can read it but definitely not write it without extra (possibly commercial) software; due to, among other things, lack of filesystem specification and aggressive patenting attitude from Microsoft. The same applies for exFAT.

Comment: @Fox "nor is it even readable by default on most Linux installations" all Linux distros I've ever used can read **and** write NTFS partitions by default for years

Comment: @ElementW: it depends on [how you implement](https://askubuntu.com/a/581903/344926)

Comment: @phuclv I haven't seen an NTFS partition in a few years, but last time I dealt with them (on Arch Linux and CentOS), I had to manually install NTFS-3G to interact with them. If things have changed since then, that's great!